# Configuring internet gateway in Ubuntu 14.04 (Desktop)

Tags: 14.04, networking, vmware, virtualbox-networking

I am sorry in advance because I asking this question using my beginner mind.
I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware. My host OS is windows 10. I want to control internet traffic of windows 10 (primary OS) with my Ubuntu (virtual machine). I have searched and checked around but every one is asking about problems in configuring, but I even don't know how to start and where to start. I am also confused about IP, broadcast and mask address, how they will behave in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With goggling any one can easily configure Internet gateway, i was confused how to link my primary OS traffic with running machine on VMWare. i could be done by:

-Edit VMWare connection settings from NAT to bridge

-go in control panel of Primary OS and assign IP and gateway you provide in OS running on VMWare.

its done :-)